# AWS SDK iOS - how to determine the percentage completion of upload request

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, progress-bar

I'm trying to update a progress view as I upload an asset to an S3 bucket like so:

```
myTransferManager.upload(myTransferManagerRequest).continueWithExecutor(myDefaultThreadBFExecutor, withBlock: { (myBFTask) -> AnyObject! in ... etc etc.
```

However, I can't figure out how to get the completion percentage of the request as it uploads. I have come across this delegate method a few times:

```
-(void)request:(AmazonServiceRequest *)request didSendData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten     totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:    (NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
{

}
```

But my project is written in Swift and I haven't been able to figure out how to implement this. For reference, I came across that method here: http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/TxIRFEQTW9XU8G/S3TransferManager-for-iOS-Part-I-Asynchronous-Uploads and here: [Uploading to Amazon-S3 via AFNetworking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10508848/uploading-to-amazon-s3-via-afnetworking)

any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,
Brendan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`AWSRequest`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/AWSCore/Networking/AWSNetworking.h#L205), which is a parent class of all AWS request objects, has properties called [`uploadProgress`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/AWSCore/Networking/AWSNetworking.h#L207) and [`downloadProgress`](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/blob/master/AWSCore/Networking/AWSNetworking.h#L208). You can use them to track the progress.